# Transposing a nxn Matrix in Python using only for/while loops

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, transpose, matrix-transform

I wanted to know why the solution I have written doesn't work:

```
def transpose(sudoku):
    n = len(sudoku)
    l_tr = [0]*n
    k = 0
    tr_sudoku = [0]*n
    while k < n:
        tr_sudoku[k] = l_tr
        k = k+1  
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(sudoku)):
        j = 0
        for j in range(len(sudoku)):
            tr_sudoku[i][j] = sudoku[j][i]
            print j, i, tr_sudoku, sudoku[i][j]
        print tr_sudoku
return tr_sudoku

correct = [[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2]]

print transpose(correct)
```

It outputs the following incorrect solution:

```
0 0 [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]] 1
1 0 [[1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0]] 2
2 0 [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]] 3
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
0 1 [[2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3]] 2
1 1 [[2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3]] 3
2 1 [[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]] 1
[[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
0 2 [[3, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1]] 3
1 2 [[3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1]] 1
2 2 [[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]] 2
[[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
[[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
```

Help would be appreciated! Thanks.

The ideal correct solution to:

```
correct = [[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,4,2]]
```

would be:

```
tr_correct = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,4,2]]
```

Comment: what (do you think) is a correct solution?

Comment: There's [a whole big library for this kind of thing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.transpose.html) unless you just really get a kick out of doing it yourself.

Comment: The core porblem is that you create the new array `tr_sudoku` that contains the SAME row `l_tr` n times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily transpose with [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def transpose(sudoku):
    return list(map(list, zip(*sudoku)))
```

Example output:

```
>>> correct = [[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2]]
>>> transpose(correct)
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
```

---

The easiest "manual" way is to switch rows and columns:

```
def transpose_manually(sudoku):
    output = sudoku[:] # new grid the same size
    for r in range(len(sudoku)): # each row
        for c in range(len(sudoku[0])): # each column
            output[c][r] = sudoku[r][c] # switch
    return output
```

Comment: bah I almost wrote this ... but the *using only for/while loops* convinced me not to (+1 anyway because this is the right way to do it imho)

Comment: It is not the transpose.

Comment: @user3286261 then I suggest you edit your question to provide the output you *are* expecting, as thebjorn suggested

Comment: This gives the correct solution. Thanks!

Jon, I do want to know what exactly was wrong with my solution, since it does the same thing as your transpose_manually does.

Comment: @user3466256 oh, sorry, got confused between the various user3xxxxxx! Yours doesn't work because `tr_sudoku[k] = l_tr` means *all rows reference the same list*. `tr_sudoku[k] = l_tr[:]` would have worked, as this creates a shallow copy of the list each time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you so much! This demonstrates a very fundamental fact about list assignment in python. It'd've taken me a long time to get here since I have only begun learning Python.